# Rails newbie here - need some help

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Rails beginner here (started with rails last Friday :-)

Back on topic! I went through [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-simple-music-streaming-app-with-ruby-on-rails/) to create an HTML5 music streaming app in Rails.

However, I can't seem to get the app to work whatsoever, as I kept getting this error:

```
NameError in SongsController#index -- uninitialized constant SongsController::BUCKET
```

After some experimenting, I "fixed" -- I'm not sure if I really fixed it, but I stopped getting that error -- by defining the `BUCKET = 'ctmusic'` in my `songs_controller.rb`.

Afterwards, I started getting the following error:

```
AWS::S3::RequestTimeTooSkewed in SongsController#index -- The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.
```

Here is the error output:

```
Started GET "/songs/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-16 16:20:41 -0500
  Processing by SongsController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 286ms

AWS::S3::RequestTimeTooSkewed (The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.):
  app/controllers/songs_controller.rb:5:in `index'

Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (14.0ms)
```

Here's [my github files](https://github.com/imjp/mp3app) so you can easily easy what might be wrong:

I'd really appreciate it if I got some help because I'm trying to make this simple app so I can learn more by editing this one app and creating something out of it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is trying to make a connection to amazon, yet if you take a look at the ID and password you provided in config/application you will notice that those are quite unlikely to be correct.

I suggest that you pick a good book. Web development with ruby on rails by the pragmatic programmer is a good choice.

Comment: Hi Nerian,

They are incorrect because I changed them to something invalid to prevent someone from using my access key and secret key :P

Comment: @imjp: I see. The common approach is to use environment variables. Any environment variable defined in your system is accessible from ruby with ENV['variable name']

Comment: I'm gonna go through the book today, thanks for the advice :)